# Yii widget, does not work redirect after validation

Tags: yii, yii-components

I have widget and call it in the layout, why is not redirect to site/search?

```
<?php
class CSearch extends CWidget
{
    public $model;
    public function init()
    {
        $this->model = new SearchForm();
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest && Yii::app()->request->getPost('FormSearch'))
        {
            $this->model->attributes = Yii::app()->request->getParam('FormSearch');
            if($this->model->validate())
            {
                $this->owner->redirect(array('site/search', 'model' => $this->model->attributes));
            }
        }
    }
    public function run()
    {
        $this->render('search', array('model' => $this->model));
    }
}
```

form

```
<div class="header-search">
    <?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'search-form',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'enableClientValidation' => true,
        'clientOptions' => array(
            'validateOnSubmit' => true,
            'validateOnChange' => false,
            'validateOnType' => false),
        'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'form-search'),
    )); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model, 'search'); ?>
        <div class="input-append">
            <?php echo $form->textField($model, 'search', array('class' => 'span2', 'placeholder' => 'Поиск')); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::htmlButton('<i class="icon-search"></i>', array('class' => 'btn', 'submit' => array('site/search')))?>
        </div>
    <?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
</div>
```

How is it done properly validated by means of a clique Yii? sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try instead:

> ```
> $this->owner->redirect(array('site/search', 'model' => $this->model->attributes));
> ```

make:

> ```
> $route_params =  $this->model->attributes;
> array_unshift($route_params, 'site/search');
> $this->owner->redirect($route_params);
> ```

It's must create URL `/site/search?field1=va1&field2=val2...`

But I look at code: your variant must works too... Than you need correctly process $_GET params, such as:

> ```
> public function run()
> {
>     if(!empty($_GET))
>     {
>         $model = new ModelAR(); // you ActiveRecord class
>         $model->attributes = $_GET;
>         $this->render('search', array('model' => $model));
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: what is error? you must change `ModelAR` to your's model, which using in redirection